# In terminal, running top, info extends past the view of the window

Tags: terminal, console, display

I assume this occurs in more terminal functions than just `top`. Is there a way to view the information without resizing the console window? I currently have my console window set to open at 80x24, which is far too short in both columns and rows to display all the information.

Comment: patrix answer is spot on.  I highly recommend [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/).  It's available in MacPorts and other alt package managers. It's colorized and is packed with view options. It resizes based on your window and allows scrolling in the vertical an horizontal directions.  You'll never you top again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can select the columns you want to display with `-stats`:

```
top -stats pid,cpu,command
```

See `man top` for a full list of available columns (listed under `-o`), the most interesting ones probably are

- `pid`: Process ID
- `command`: The name of the command
- `cpu`: CPU usage
- `time`: Execution time
- `vsize`: Total memory size
- `state`: Process state
- `uid`: User ID (or `user` for user name)

Comment: At the risk of being redundant here, is there no native scrolling support in terminal for either axis to handle overflow content? I dont want to sound ungrateful either.  I definitely appreciate the alternate methods for achieving the end-result in top, I could easily see the same scenario occur in other functions.